# GCP Cloud SQL Server Connection issue from local

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Just created Cloud SQL Server Instance in GCP but not able to connect to GCP Cloud SQL instance from local microsoft sql server studio using public IP address. Does it require any additional settings?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I could able to resolve. Go to instance=>connections=>Public IP=> Authorized Network=> Add the IP address where sql studio is installed.
[image]